# On one property of positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, semidefinite-programming, positive-semidefinite

This question reveals some important properties of positive semidefinite matrices. It would be very useful in solving the SDP problem (where I encountered it). The question is quite straightforward.

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ positive semidefinite matrix with positive diagonal elements. Is it possible that any of its $2 \times 2$ submatrices defined as:
>
> $$
> \begin{bmatrix} a_{ii} & a_{ij}  \\a_{ji} & a_{jj}\end{bmatrix}
> $$
>
> is not positive semidefinite?
>
> And if every this $2\times2$ submatrix is positive semidefinite, is A necessarily positive semidefinite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The submatrix you mention is necessarily positive semidefinite.   In particular, if $e_1,\dots,e_n$ are the standard basis vectors, then it suffices to note that
$$
(x_ie_i + x_je_j)^TA(x_ie_i + x_je_j) = \pmatrix{x_i&x_j} \pmatrix{a_{ii} & a_{ij}\\ a_{ji} & a_{jj}}\pmatrix{x_i\\x_j}\geq 0
$$
for any choice of $x_i,x_j$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very good answer!

Comment: What about the inverse? If every $ 2\times 2$ submatrix is positive semidefinite, is A necessarily a positive semidefinite matrix?

Comment: I assume you're talking specifically about *principal* submatrices, then

Comment: I suspect not, but it's a reasonable question to ask.  I would start a new post for the inverse question.

Comment: I'm quite certain it is not. It will conflict some result I already got from the data.

Comment: I posted a new question which is related to this one. You may take a look if you are interested. Thank you.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935164/completion-of-2-times-2-psd-rank-1-partial-matrix