# Completion of $2 \times 2$ positive semidefinite rank-$1$ partial matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, semidefinite-programming, positive-semidefinite, matrix-completion

This question is related to one property of rank-$1$, positive semidefinite matrices. Would be very useful in SDP problems (which is where I found it).

> Consider a $3 \times 3$ positive semidefinite rank-$1$ matrix $A = xx^H$
>   $$
> $$
>   \begin{bmatrix} x_1x^H_1 & x_1x^H_2 & x_1x^H_3 \\x_2x^H_1 & x_2x^H_2 & x_2x^H_3\\x_3x^H_1 & x_3x^H_2 & x_3x^H_3\end{bmatrix}
>   $$ 
> $$
>   Now let matrix $B$ as a partial matrix of $A$ defined as:
>   $$
> $$
>   \begin{bmatrix} x_1x^H_1 & x_1x^H_2 & x_1x^H_3 \\x_2x^H_1 & x_2x^H_2 & \\x_3x^H_1 &  & x_3x^H_3\end{bmatrix}
>   $$ 
> $$
>   Is it possible that any completion of matrix $B$ be positive semidefinite but not $A$ (or, equivalently, psd but not rank-$1$)?
>   I think it is impossible, but I don't know how to prove it. If it is possible, you can either tell me why or use real number as a counter example.

Comment: $2 \times 2$???

Comment: Matrix B is a partial matrix which is 2x2 psd rank-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may employ Sylvester's criterion (for positive semidefinite matrices).

Comment: Thank you. In fact just setting the determinant of B to be nonnegative will achieve the same result.